# PVC-oriented executor pod allocation with spark-on-k8s-operator

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, spark-operator

I see in the documentation that there is an option of [PVC-oriented executor pod allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#pvc-oriented-executor-pod-allocation) that from my understanding should help with spot instances decommission.
I couldn't find how to use it with the [spark-on-k8s-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/tree/master).

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is accualy not really a problem and the configuration can be added under `sparkConf`.

```
  sparkConf:
    spark.kubernetes.driver.ownPersistentVolumeClaim: "true"
    spark.kubernetes.driver.reusePersistentVolumeClaim: "true"
    spark.kubernetes.driver.waitToReusePersistentVolumeClaim: "true"
```